# $(a^2+1)(b^2+1) = c^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all natural $a,b,c$ such that $a^2+1$ and $b^2+1$ are primes and the equation $(a^2+1)(b^2+1) = c^2+1$ is satisfied. I don't know how to approach this problem at all. The only thing I could do was to notice that $a$ and $b$ must be distinct. Then I've done some plugging in order to look for some pattern. The only sols that I found was $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3$ and $a = 2, b = 1, c = 3$, but I concluded nothing from this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may find many relevant posts on MSE as well as on AoPS here: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(a%5E2%2B1)(b%5E2%2B1)%20%3D%20c%5E2%2B1%24&p=1

Comment: To a first glance if you want to approach the problem brutally you should first have to find two primes $p,q$ such that $pq = c^2 + 1$ for some $c$. Then you try to understand if $p$ and $q$ can be both written in the form $p = a^2 + 1$ and $q = b^2 + 1$

Comment: You can consider    transformed formula $(a^2+1)(b^2+1) = (ab)^2+ a^2+b^2 +1= c^2+1$
from which you have   

$(ab)^2+ a^2+b^2 = c^2 $

and look at  
 [Numbers that are the sum of three nonzero squares. ][1].
 


  [1]: http://oeis.org/A000408

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple